# Spring querydsl predicate: relationship support

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, querydsl

I have a Client entity with an OneToOne relation with Contact.
If I want to get the client name, I need to write:

```
 client.getContact().getLastName()
```

I use querydsl lib to filters client list in my spring boot app

```
 /api/clients?contact.lastName=Doe
```

My controller signature:

```
 public ResponseEntity<ResponseListDTO> getClients (
        @QuerydslPredicate(root = Client.class) Predicate predicateClient,
        Pageable pageable)
```

It works well: predicate is well created and filters works.

But now I need to filter on a field inside two relationship level:

```
 client.getContact().getAddress().getCity()
```

So I wan't to write:

```
 /api/clients?contact.address.city=XXX
```

But its not mapped with @QuerydslPredicate. No error but the @QuerydslPredicate predicate is still null (like if no filters).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution with `@QueryInit` here: http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/4.0.7/reference/html_single/#d0e2245